# Selenium java can not find the right element

Tags: java, selenium

I want to find the element for a checkbox on the page:

this is the source code of the page:

```
<tr>
                        <td class="tablecell"  width="200" valign="top">Filter_list</td>
                        <td class="tablecell"  width="360">
                            <div id="div_filterlist">
                                <table border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="tablecell"  width="160" valign="top"><b>Available Filters</b><br>
                                            <ul id="unselected_ilters" class="unselected_filter">

                                                <li itemID="test">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="test" onClick="toggleUnselected(this,'test')" onMouseOver="this.style.cursor='hand'"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                    <a href="#" onClick="document.filterform.name.value='test';document.filterform.submit();">test</a>
                                                </li>
```

My code is not working:

```
String xpathLocater = "//input[ @type=\"checkbox\" and @value=\" test\"]";
```

Comment: in which way your code is not working? any exception?

Comment: are you able to edit the HTML of the page?

Comment: I got "Unable to locate element:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css selector:
`String cssLocator = "input[type=checkbox]";` or
`String cssLocator = "input[type=checkbox][value=test]";`

xpath selector:
`String xpathLocator = "//input[@type=\"checkbox\"]";` or
`String xpathLocator = "//input[@type=\"checkbox\" and @value=\"test\"]";`

If you still can't find the element check 2 things:

- whether that element inside iframe: if yes - you need to switch to
  iframe first
- add wait before finding an element (you could try to
  find element before it was added to DOM)

Comment: not working String xpathLocater = "//input[ @type=\"checkbox\" and @value=\" test\"]";

Comment: it should. can you share the link to web page or give more html snippet?

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type=\"checkbox\" and @value=\"NewAlarm\"]"}

Comment: this sis the xpath link to the element: html/body/form[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/ul/li[1]/input

Comment: two form in one page, <form name="alarmform" action="viewalarmdef.jsp" method="post">

Comment: If you found solution feel free to answer on your own question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97899/discussion-between-peter-and-drets).